# jQuery jqgrid add all rows at once

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

hello Im new to using jqgrid.  is there a way to create a grid with a set of rows based off the length all at once instead of a loop?

The way we are currently doing it seems to causing alot of overhead on the client.

```
var c = 0;
for ( var j = 0; i < pageData.length; j++) {

                            var myata = pageData[j];
                            $("#myGrid").jqGrid('addRowData', + 1, myData);
                            c++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have array with data you should better use `datatype: "local", data: myData` option of jqGrid. I recommend you additionally use `gridview: true` option for better performance. You should take in consideration that jqGrid *always* assign `id` attribute to every row of the grid (to `<tr>` elements). I recommend you include `id` property in every element of `myData` array which will be used as the rowid (it have to be unique).  By adding the option `data: myData` jqGrid will create grid, sort the data corresponds to `sortname` and `sortorder` options and display the first page of data. You can use either `toppager: true` or `pager` option to diplay pager in the grid.

Comment: @DocHoliday: You question was about adding all rows at once ("is there a way to create a grid with a set of rows based off the length all at once instead of a loop?"). My answer parameter `data` do the job. If you want *no paging* you should add `rowNum: 10000` (or some other large value). If you want local paging then you should create the pager (on the top or on the bottom of the grid).

Comment: `var myData = pageData;
        $('#myGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: myData}).trigger('reloadGrid');`

Comment: @DocHoliday: Your original question was: "is there a way to create a grid with a set of rows". `data` parameter is the best way to do it. The code `$('#myGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: pageData}).trigger('reloadGrid');` means how to *update* data of the grid. By the way it not correct update the data. It *merge* old data with the new one (see [the source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2879-L2883) which uses `$.extend(true, ...)`). To reload the grid with new data one have to reset the `data` first to empty array and then one can use `setGridParam`.

Comment: Correct code to *update* the data can be for example the following: `var refInternalData = $("#myGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"); refInternalData = []; $('#myGrid').jqGrid("setGridParam", {data: pageData}).trigger("reloadGrid");`